# mouseenter same item on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have edited a script to act as I need it..

I need the #currentitem to mouseenter on page load, mouseleave when another item triggers a mouseenter (so not to overlap).

I have a problem where it all works as intended. Apart from when I mouseleave the #currentitem I need its dropdown to stay visible. So the only time it is not visible (or mouseenter) is when mouseenter the other menu items.

I have created a JSFiddle where the current item is the 'About Us' menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/qFS84/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#currentitem a").trigger('mouseenter');
});
$(".submenu").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#currentitem").trigger('mouseleave');
});
$(".submenu").mouseleave(function(){
   $("#currentitem a").trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682100/mouseenter-triggered-on-page-load-if-no-other-mouseenter-event-is-triggered

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress on your issue hopefully it helps a little.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2zMz/5/

```
$('#currentitem').mouseout(function(){
    $("#currentitem > a").trigger('mouseenter');
})
```

this biggest problem was that you were looking for events that happened on element with the class .submenu but your element you were listening for didn't have the class .submenu.